# Swift 4 Conform Comparable protocol and sort method issue

Tags: swift, sorting

I write following Struct that conform to protocol Comparable.

```
struct Record: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Record, rhs: Record) -> Bool {
        if lhs.wins == rhs.wins {
            return lhs.losses > rhs.losses
        }
        return lhs.wins < rhs.wins
    }

    var wins: Int
    var losses: Int

    init(wins: Int, losses: Int) {
        self.wins = wins
        self.losses = losses
    }
}

var a1 = Record(wins: 3, losses: 8)
var b1 = Record(wins: 3, losses: 9)
var c1 = Record(wins: 4, losses: 7)

var records = [a1, b1, c1]

records.reverse()
print(records)
```

It all works fine using > < == and sort too. but if I reverse sort method on array of records, It gives me output as follows:

> [__lldb_expr_48.Record(wins: 4, losses: 7), __lldb_expr_48.Record(wins: 3, losses: 9), __lldb_expr_48.Record(wins: 3, losses: 8)]

Highest wins should come first followed by less wins but if wins are equal then less losses should come before more losses. Am I doing anything wrong here or missing something? I am still learning swift so might be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To order an array of stuff in the reverse sort order, you can just `sort` by `>`:

```
records.sort(by: >)
```

`reverse` will just reverse the array, without sorting it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought reverse function is for reverse sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You just don't sort your array before you reverse it

```
records.sort()
records.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a universal way to sort however you want without conforming to Comparable protocol. It might be useful if you apply various sorting logic in different places or just do sorting infrequently. Try this one:

```
struct SimpleRecord {
    var wins: Int
    var losses: Int
    var name: String
    // we get a simple init for free
}

let a = SimpleRecord(wins: 3, losses: 8, name: "abc")
let b = SimpleRecord(wins: 3, losses: 9, name: "some ")
let c = SimpleRecord(wins: 4, losses: 7, name: "abc")
let d = SimpleRecord(wins: 3, losses: 8, name: "Abc")

var simpleRecords = [a, b, c, d]

simpleRecords.sort(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    if lhs.wins > rhs.wins {
        return true
    } else if lhs.wins == rhs.wins {
        if lhs.losses < rhs.losses {
            return true
        } else if lhs.losses == rhs.losses {
            return (lhs.name.localizedStandardCompare(rhs.name) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending)
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }
})

// print(simpleRecords) // it is a lazy collection so print is a bit messy
simpleRecords.forEach{ print($0) }
```

Note, how we can use non-trivial (yet efficient) predefined sorting algorithms for strings (from Foundation) such as 'localizedStandardCompare', 'localizedCompare' and etc.